# What are right or best analysis method on finding voltage, current and ohm in circuit analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law, nodal-analysis, superposition, mesh-analysis

I'm new to electrical engineering. In the few past weeks, I already learn about different analyses to find what to find. Like finding voltage, current, and ohm with different methods. Examples like Ohm laws, Kirchoff 1 and 2 laws, node, supernode, mesh, super mesh, superposition, Thevenin theorem, and Norton theorem. So I already learn the method that I write above, but I feel confused when there is a question with a circuit. Besides that, I have little 'flight time' or experience in using them. Are there any unwritten rules for finding that asked the question given based on the circuit?

For example like on these circuits:

[image]

Find V based on that question.

If I try to solve it, I will go to use superposition (so there are two sources, except the controlled current source) and for current source superposition I'll use node analysis, and for the voltage source, I'll use mesh. I'm not sure if my solution is right or not and that's the reason I'm asking here. What is the best method or analysis for example circuit like this?

Comment: As one professor of mine would say it: "A circuit doesn't know how it's going to be analyzed." Different (correct) methods should lead to identical results. One method might be easier than another for a given circuit. It's easier to make accidental mistakes once a solving method is more involved. The only way to know what is 'the best' (read: the easiest, or more direct) way to solve a given circuit, is experience.

To check your solution, you could see whether KCL and KVL are satisfied for all loops and nodes. Alternatively, you could input the circuit in a simulator to check your solution.

Comment: A circuit that complicated is rather throwing you in the deep end. If you have multiple sources, then superposition is a good place to start, as it separates the solution into several simpler ones. Remember, good decisions come from experience. Experience comes from bad decisions. Just do it, do it again, and again, and don't get too stressed about getting it wrong sometimes, and you'll gradually build experience. There's no real short cut.

Comment: User, what's the "3V A" mean in the dependent source there? And is it a current controlled current source? Or a voltage controlled current source?